# What are the requirements for the new Camera V3 module on Debian Buster?

Tags: camera, libcamera

I am currently trying to get the Camera V3 module up and running on Debian Buster.
I already managed to get it running with `libcamera` which I downloaded and compiled from source, so the connection and camera are working.

I would love to replace an old V2 camera with the new model on an octopi, so I wonder what the requirements for the new camera are.

- does in only work with `libcamera`?
- what are the general requirements for the camera on older systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. here is my own experience:

- the Camera V3 modules need the `libcamera` module.
- If you install it via `sudo apt install libcamera-apps`, it will not contain the config for the Camera V3 module.
- Solution is to compile it from the raspberry sources
- the Camera V2 modules also work with the `libcamera` module
- libcamara is still beta
- raspian bullseye is setup to use libcamera

conclusion:

- you can't just plug-and-play a v3 camera to an older system. Even when you upgrade your system to bullseye, chance are that the camera support breaks
- nevertheless, libcamera and bullseye are the way forward